# how to read all the csv files in folder sequentially, filter all csv file by using a category in one column.Finally merge all

Tags: csv

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = r'J:POI'

filtered_dataframes = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        
        filtered_df = df[df['cityname'] == 'CD']
        filtered_dataframes.append(filtered_df)

merged_dataframe = pd.concat(filtered_dataframes)

output_file_path = r'J:POI\CD2018.csv'
merged_dataframe.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)
```

how to read all the csv in folder,and how  to filter according one attribution